# USB drives don't show in Files

Tags: files, usb-drive, fdisk

Sometimes I can't see USB drives in `Files` although they appear when doing `sudo fdisk -l`.
In `Files` a little flash manifests itself in the window when unplugging the USB drive. But plugging/unplugging doesn't work.
Where could it come from ?

Comment: May be the drives are not mounted for some reason. Try the "Disks" utility.

Comment: The drives are correctly mounted (verified in the Disk utility). The problem doesn't show up every time, just some times. It may be a problem from the file viewer as suggested by @lhimotsupotatometro